# How does one discern the error number of a MySQL execution in Go?

Tags: mysql, go

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("SQL Stuff")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
res, err := stmt.Exec(add a variable)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

This is how I am currently handling my MySQL based errors in Go.

As it stands when I run into trouble with my SQL command or something else an error comes through, hits the 'if' and properly prints the error to the console ending the program.

I know when I see the console reading there are error numbers like these : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html .

So I would assume that the thrown error itself has the number inside of it. I'd like to respond to situations like "The row is present" or "Not a unique value" because in some situations I have responses for them.

Is there a succinct method to discerning what the error number is?

Comment: So you want to create a new error with the defined response for that error.

Comment: @Himanshu   I am unsure if I am using the right semantics ... But... I am wanting to know if the variable 'err' has a property that can be accessed in Go that will tell me what exactly the error type is. In Python in my "try...except..." blocks I could specify "indexError" or "readError" and handle each situation based on the type of issue I ran into. Can I handle errors like that in Go? :)

Comment: In golang the error is an interface which returns the whole error including the line number. For exact message you can use `err.Error()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which MySQL driver you're using. If it is `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`, then it does expose the error number in the [MySQLError type](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#MySQLError). You could do something like this:

```
if merr, ok := err.(*mysql.MySQLError); ok {
    // This is an error from MySQL. Use merr.Number as the error number
} else {
    // This error isn't necessarily from MySQL. Usual error processing
}
```